# Session always store the previous value

Tags: session

I'm developing a email sending form. It has a captcha security image. When ever I refresh the image to load new captcha it always stores the previous session value. It never stores the correct one.

But in my localhost it works fine. Thank you very much.

```
class CaptchaSecurityImages {

    var $font = 'monofont.ttf';

    function generateCode($characters) {
        /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
        $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $characters) { 
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }

        $_SESSION['securitycode'] = $code;

        return $code;
    }

    function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
        $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
        /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
        $_SESSION['securitycode'] = $code;      
        $font_size = $height * 0.75;
        $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
        /* set the colours */
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
        $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
        /* generate random dots in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
            imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
        }
        /* generate random lines in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
            imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
        }
        /* create textbox and add text */
        $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
        $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
        $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
        /* output captcha image to browser */
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);


    }

}
```

This is the class I'm using to generate captcha.

Comment: Not a lot of information to go on here. How about some code?

Comment: This works in localhost. But not working in server.

Comment: anybody know anything why session value cannot be replaced by new value.